# I am a beginner in C, could anybody please help me with the output

Tags: c

I need to add the numbers in the row array mentioned in the structure.
for example I need the output of row=[ 4  5 6]
and age= 25, how can i do with the above mentioned structure?? 
Please help !

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct person
{
    int row[1];
    int age;
} PERSON;

int main()
{
    PERSON p;
    PERSON *pptr=&p;

    pptr->row[1] = 4;
    pptr->age = 25;
    printf("%d\n",pptr->row[1]);
    printf("%d\n",pptr->age);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be asking a specific question.

Comment: What problem are you facing with your code?

Comment: Please reformat the question so that it readable, and clarify what issue you are having.  You probably need `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: sorry for that, thanks to vincent for editing.

Comment: Actually i need the output of 4 and 25 , but when i compile Iam getting the output as 25 and 25..

Comment: So add it to your question instead of writing a comment.

Comment: I need to add the numbers in the row array mentioned in the structure.
for example I need the output of row=[ 4  5 6]
and age= 25, how can i do with the above mentioned structure?? 
Please help !

Comment: So why you declared an array of size 1 if you want to put 3 elements inside it?

Comment: @Reshmy - I updated based on your specific comment... let me know if you understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I need to add the numbers in the row array mentioned in the structure. for example I need the output of row=[ 4 5 6] and age= 25, how can i do with the above mentioned structure?? Please help !`

Based on this update:

Put the number of elements you want to store into the array defination:

```
int row[1]; // This stores 1 element of type int

// you want to store 3 elements: 4, 5, 6, so...

int row[3];  // This is what you're looking for
```

Remember an array:

```
int row[X];
```

Goes from `row[0]` to `row[X-1]`. So in your case `X=3` that means your min/max values for your array are:

```
min = row[0]
max = row[3-1] = row[2]
```

That means your code should do something like:

```
pptr->row[0] = 4;
pptr->row[1] = 5;
pptr->row[2] = 6;
pptr->age = 25;
printf("%d\n",pptr->row[0]);
printf("%d\n",pptr->row[1]);
printf("%d\n",pptr->row[2]);
printf("%d\n",pptr->age);
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, its clear now.

Comment: Is it possible to print all the values in the structure in one go, instead of accessing individual members(data-in my case row and age) in the structure.

Comment: @Reshmy - You can print them on in one line `printf("%d, %d, %d %d\n", pptr->row[0], pptr->row[1], pptr->row[2], pptr->age);` but there's no good, built in, reliable way to print all the elements of a structure in one shot.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking why the line

```
printf("%d\n",pptr->row[1]);
```

returns the value for `age`?  This is because `int row[1];` declares an array with one element but `pptr->row[1]` tries to access the second element of the array (array indexes are zero based).  In other words, you are writing to memory beyond the end of your allocated array.

The effects of doing this are undefined but it wouldn't be surprising if the memory pointed at by `pptr->row[1]` was actually `pptr->age`

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, its clear now.

Answer (score 1):

In C, arrays begin in 0 position:

```
int row[1];
```

means an array of just one int.

The first position is:

```
pptr->row[0] = 4;
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, its clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in C, an N-element array is indexed from 0 to N-1.  For example:

```
int arr[5];

arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
arr[3] = 4;
arr[4] = 5;
```

Since you've declared the `row` member of your `struct` as a 1-element array<sup>1</sup>, the lines

```
pptr->row[1] = 4;
```

and

```
printf("%d\n", pptr->row[1]);
```

are accessing memory outside of the bounds of your array; the behavior upon doing so is *undefined*, so pretty much anything can happen.

---

<sup>1.  It's not clear what the intent is here.  What use is a 1-element array, unless you want `row` to be treated as a pointer in most contexts?</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

In all your code use

```
pptr->row[0]
```

instead of

```
pptr->row[1]
```

The size of the row array is 1 and the index of array in C start from 0 and not from 1

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, its clear now.